# How to complete some part of form in another page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I made a contact form for the users to complete in their profile.

It consists of some simple fields like address and phone number and a location field to choose their coordination on a map.

However, I want the location field on another page. For instance, when a user wants to fill this form, they first fill in other fields, then by clicking a button they get redirected to another page to fill the location field and then again return to the form and submit everything.

Is this even possible? How can I submit part of a form on a page and the rest on another page?

Answer (score 0):

What i want to say that make the form model fields blank true and null true then while you want to create multi step form first take the data and fill the form and save it but best thing i suggest you to make a single form javascript which will fill the data then you can save the whole form at once
Here is an example which can help you [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)

Comment: can you explain more? this is uncharted territory for me

Comment: bro  i have updated my answer with more deatils good luck